# Add text to the label element search bar Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a [search bar in the Wordpress navigation menu](https://wordpress.brunoc.ovh), for this I added this in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'sydney_child_add_serch_from_to_nav', 10, 2);
function sydney_child_add_serch_from_to_nav($items, $args){

  if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
      $items .= '<li class="top-search-menu">'.get_search_form(false).'</li>';
  }
  return $items;

}
```

The problem being that my sites [must be valid WCAG 2.0 (Level A)](https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php), but I have the following error:

[image]

I tried several solutions to add a label but without success. I have the same error when using a search plugins.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `get_search_form` can easily use your own search form template from inside your theme.

Comment: Can you tell me more? I created a child theme, do you think the problem with this?

Comment: No, I just looked up the documentation for the function, and there it says what template it is looking for right away. So, what more do you need, than to create one in your own theme, and add the label …?

Comment: I don't know where I should add the label.

Comment: The default search form should contain a label element already, as far as I can see from the code. And the error message you quoted complains that the label text was empty, not that the element itself was missing. Did you perhaps translate the text that is output there with an empty string or something? (Talking about https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php#L160)

Comment: I did not modify any translation string. To inform the parent theme does not contain a searchform.php file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So does your search form that is generated look more or less like what the code at the linked position looks like? Same structure, same class names, …? (Asking to figure out first of all if that’s were your search form comes from, or whether that has been overwritten by something else already.)